# File System vs Web Deploy of Website on Local LAN - Which is Better?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, web-publishing

Our production website is available via our Local LAN.  Since it's been available, I've used File System deployment to move our site into production.  I know Web Deploy has been available for some time, but with the release of VS2012, I'm wondering if there are specific advantages of using Web Deploy over File System, keeping in mind that we are publishing over a 1Gbps connection.  Also, I don't use any of the database updating features of Publishing.

Answer (score 2):

It's really whichever you like better. I've tried out both and don't see any real advantages which would make one superior